# Can a property have a method?

Tags: c#

Can a property GridTerminalSystem have a method named GetBlockWithName?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var InteriorLight = GridTerminalSystem.GetBlockWithName("Interior Light") as IMyInteriorLight;
        InteriorLight.ApplyAction("OnOff_On");
    }
}
```

Comment: Homework question?  This is basic stuff... try google or get a book I guess.

Comment: If that's actually the case.  You should still take that advice.  You're going to struggle with any type of code if you don't understand the basics.

Comment: what happens when you do a google search on the following `C# GridTerminalSystem`

Comment: @Hester new to programming or not.. there are such things as Tutorials and C# Books out there.. start off by reading / learning the basics.. stop using `I am new to programming` as an excuse to stop your from doing research on your own..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us [what you have tried](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var InteriorLight = GridTerminalSystem.GetBlockWithName("Interior Light") as IMyInteriorLight;
```

Here you are calling the static method `GetBlockWithName` of class `GridTerminalSystem` and passing in a string  argument `"Interior Light"`. Then, the result is being casted to `IMyInteriorLight`, and assigned to `InteriorLight` variable.

```
InteriorLight.ApplyAction("OnOff_On");
```

Here you are calling the method `ApplyAction` on the `IMyInteriorLight` instance that was previously assigned to `InteriorLight`. You are passing in a string `"OnOff_On"` to the method. Apparently, the method does not return anything (`void`), as there is no assignment.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Could GridTerminalSystem be a property?

Comment: @Hester Yes, of course. I assumed it wasn't because I didn't see it on your `Program` class declaration

Comment: Matias is it possible for the InteriorLight to hold an object?

Comment: @Hester It *does* hold an object. It is holding a `IMyInteriorLight` instance.